# How to deactivate hacking of my ECU and an additional tracker that's placed without my consent

Tags: electronic-control-module, immobilizer

My fear / opinion is that my vehicle's ECU has been hacked. I'm worried about going full speed and someone suddenly stops my vehicle remotely with their installed immobilizer.

I'm aware vehicles have immobilizer and that's not my concern. However I'm worried there's an additional perp added part that can control ecu Or just a separate immobilizer added.

Where I live GPS scramblers are not allowed. Basically, jammers are illegal here. Talking to a local mechanic won't be much helpful because the perps would also then get involved with the consultant.

My vehicle is TVS Jupiter.

Much Regards & Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: While jammers are illegal where you are at, are snoopers? Can you get a detector and try to find the tracker signal itself? Also, they may be able to hack your vehicles ECU, but unless they are tied into it and transmitting/receiving, they cannot do anything with it. There is nothing "built into" the vehicle which would allow anyone to control without a direct connection. Considering you are talking about a motor bike/scooter, adding something like this would not only be improbable, it is also not likely. You could take the covers off your scooter and find something like that easily.

Answer (score 1):

Your ecu is not capable of doing the control you think, there would need to be an external device attached to it so you can simply check the wiring from the ecu and look for out of place parts. If something look suspicious check its part number. Things that do not belong usually stand out pretty well.

I don't think the concern would be cutting the engine of the scooter while your driving since you would still just roll to a stop. More likely they would want to control acceleration where you could not slow down. Inspecting your communication lines, brake wiring and your throttle control wiring from pedal to ecu for splices/devices would be a great place to start.